# If domain admin account's NTLM hash is compromised, can it be used to access any machine in network

Tags: hash, system-compromise

If a hacker able to get local admin rights and then from there local domain admin's NTLM hash.

Can he use this hash without cracking, to access shared folders in the network and the default C drive share on all network machines ?

I know he himself using local account he compromised can become domain admin by several ways. But would that be detectable ?

What would be the most passive way to move forward for him ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called the [Pass the Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash) attack.

Microsoft has not issued any solution to mitigate (except for some vague general security advice), until Windows 10 where the hash is stored in a special vault.

An example of exploit (via Metasploit) can be found at [Offensive Security](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/psexec-pass-hash/).